# Extract chat id from https://web.telegram.org/z/ using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, telegram

I want to extract the chat-id from telegram web version **z**. I have done it on the telegram web version **k** but, it is not present in the **z** version. I looked every where but could not find any element containing chat-id. I know I can get the chat-id from url after opening the chat, but I can not open chat due to some reason.
The following is the basic code to open the telegram.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import sys

URL = 'https://web.telegram.org/'
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
path_to_firefox_profile = "output_files\\firefox\\ghr2wgpa.default-release"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path_to_firefox_profile)
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
firefox_options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", 'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0')
profile.set_preference("security.mixed_content.block_active_content", False)
profile.update_preferences()
firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1400")
firefox_options.add_argument("--height=1000")
driver_installation = GeckoDriverManager().install()
service = Service(driver_installation)
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
    service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, firefox_profile=profile, capabilities = caps,
                            service=service)

driver.get(URL)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

I only know is that the chat-id is being passed to some function in common.js when we click on the chat to open it.
The chat-id is available as the following attribute.

*data-peer-id="777000"*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal - to open a chat first, so I think you may link not to id first, but to the name, I see in the tree of this version:

```
<div class="ListItem Chat chat-item-clickable group selected no-selection has-ripple"....
     <div class="ListItem-button"
       <div class="info"
          <div class="info-row"
            <h3 class="fullName" > Unique name is here>
```

So, as an option, you find unique chat via its name, open it, and grab the id from url, coz the chat will be already open.

Comment: I know about the fullName but I have to get the chat-id without opening the chat.